# How to delete a node in menu system when user updated a specific content type article

Tags: nodes, routes, rules

I have built a content type and some taxonomy

There is a problem in my site for now if I selected taxonomy one my node will become to the taxonomy one children in the menu system and if I edited the node changed taxonomy one to the taxonomy two the node will become to the taxonomy two children in the menu system

but the node still exist in the taxonomy one menu system

how can I deleted it when an user updated the node?

I have written some code to achieve this and It work well but I can't delete the node in the taxonomy one children

There are some coding ~

Thank you

```
function  hellosanta_node_update($node){
$type=$node->type;

if($type="language_of_the_god"){

    $taxonomy=$node->field_taxonomy['und'][0]['value'];
    if($taxonomy=="god"){

        unset($node->field_taxonomy2);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy3);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy4);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy5);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy6);  

        //delete node link from menu
        $arr = menu_node_get_links($node->nid);
        //dpm($arr);
          $arr('delete',$node);     

        //add link to 什麼是與神對話
        $item = array(
            'link_path' => 'node/' . $node->nid,
            'link_title' => $node->title,
            'menu_name' => 'main-menu', // Menu machine name, for example: main-menu
            'weight' => 0,
            'language' => $node->language,
            'plid' => 696, // Parent menu item, 0 if menu item is on top level
            'module' => 'menu',
        );          

        menu_link_save($item);

    }
    elseif($taxonomy=="confusing"){

        unset($node->field_taxonomy1);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy3);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy4);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy5);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy6);

        //delete node link from menu
        $arr = menu_node_get_links($node->nid);
        //dpm($arr);
          $arr('delete',$node); 


        $item = array(
            'link_path' => 'node/' . $node->nid,
            'link_title' => $node->title,
            'menu_name' => 'main-menu', // Menu machine name, for example: main-menu
            'weight' => 0,
            'language' => $node->language,
            'plid' => 593, // Parent menu item, 0 if menu item is on top level
            'module' => 'menu',         
        );

        menu_link_save($item);

    }
    elseif($taxonomy=="wisdom"){
        unset($node->field_taxonomy1);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy2);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy4);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy5);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy6);

        $item = array(
            'link_path' => 'node/' . $node->nid,
            'link_title' => $node->title,
            'menu_name' => 'main-menu', // Menu machine name, for example: main-menu
            'weight' => 0,
            'language' => $node->language,
            'plid' => 594, // Parent menu item, 0 if menu item is on top level
            'module' => 'menu',         
        );

        menu_link_save($item);  
    }
    elseif($taxonomy=="community"){
        unset($node->field_taxonomy1);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy2);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy3);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy5);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy6);

        $item = array(
            'link_path' => 'node/' . $node->nid,
            'link_title' => $node->title,
            'menu_name' => 'main-menu', // Menu machine name, for example: main-menu
            'weight' => 0,
            'language' => $node->language,
            'plid' => 595, // Parent menu item, 0 if menu item is on top level
            'module' => 'menu',         
        );

        menu_link_save($item);  
    }
    elseif($taxonomy=="life"){
        unset($node->field_taxonomy1);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy2);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy3);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy4);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy6);

        $item = array(
            'link_path' => 'node/' . $node->nid,
            'link_title' => $node->title,
            'menu_name' => 'main-menu', // Menu machine name, for example: main-menu
            'weight' => 0,
            'language' => $node->language,
            'plid' => 596, // Parent menu item, 0 if menu item is on top level
            'module' => 'menu',         
        );

        menu_link_save($item);  
    }
    elseif($taxonomy=="education"){
        unset($node->field_taxonomy1);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy2);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy3);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy4);
        unset($node->field_taxonomy5);

        $item = array(
            'link_path' => 'node/' . $node->nid,
            'link_title' => $node->title,
            'menu_name' => 'main-menu', // Menu machine name, for example: main-menu
            'weight' => 0,
            'language' => $node->language,
            'plid' => 597, // Parent menu item, 0 if menu item is on top level
            'module' => 'menu',         
        );

        menu_link_save($item);  
    }   
}
}
```